# MVC's service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, asp.net-mvc-5

My MVC's controller actions are getting huge. I want to create a service layer so that I can move code there. The idea is to use the SOLID principle: the controllers use the service layer to get the domain models that will be then transformed into view models.

My question is simple: Should my service layer be a new assembly (project) that will go along with my MVC project or should it be simply a class inside my already existing assembly (MVC Project)?

My approach will be similar to the following one, but unfortunately the post doesn't explain exactly how was the service layer defined:
http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/06/20/asp-net-mvc-moving-code-from-controller-action-to-service-layer.aspx

Comment: That's a matter of opinion, so you might get better answers over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RGraham is right about the forum, but I would say it should be in a separate assembly.  Right now, you might only have a single UI, but then lets say you want to go mobile, you won't be able to reuse that service layer if it is in the assembly with the MVC.  There are other advantages to separating it out as well

Comment: Thanks @RGraham & ken4z. So, if I select to create a new assembly, should it be a library class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider making the service layer a separate thing.

Service can be an interface-based object that is implemented either in-memory in the application or distributed and accessed remotely via SOAP, REST, RCP-XML, or anything else.  The controller/client need not know or care if they have a client program that's interface based as well.

A dependency injection, interface based solution would allow you to inject client and service implementations in pairs so controllers need not be disturbed if you change how to access the services.

Controller is usually closely tied to a view.  Views come and go, but services tend to remain.  Services should map to business functionality that could be shared across applications.

Comment: thanks! I guess you mean I must declare my service layer inside a new project (class library). Right?

Comment: The interfaces will have to be shared, but the implementations for client and server should be separate DLLs.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand. I'm an MVC newbie. My Solution has one assembly that initially used the "ASP.Net Web Application" template. In order to create this new "service layer" assembly I was thinking about selecting the template "class library". Is this the right move?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about .NET.  I think it'd be a separate DLL that you'd add in, just like a 3rd party library.  Except the provider is you.

Answer (score 2):

> Should my service layer be a new assembly (project)

Yes, it should. Other UIs might want to use it in the future...

Comment: in that case, should the new assembly be a library class or should I choose a different option?

Comment: A library class. Going forward, parts of that service layer can be exposed via, for example, web services.

Comment: A class library you mean :) perfect

Comment: You can inject your data layer into the service layer - ensuring it is loosely coupled. E.g. a change of database should not cause any changes in the service layer.